# How to publish an organization repository in Github using VSCode

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I added my files and commited with no problem.
The problem is that when I press "Publish to Github" the only options there appear are private and public repositories as individual.
But I would like to publish as an organization.
[image]

Comment: create the repository on Github, clone the repo, copy the files, and push

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Github Desktop allows you to choose the organization to publish. Just click the "publish repository" and choose the organization to publish at the bottom list.

Answer (score 39):

**Workaround for the lack of functionality:**

You can add your project to a local repository by pressing "Initialize Repository" in your "Source Control" tab.

After that, go to Github and make a new empty organisation repository.

Now you can hit F1 and type "Add Remote". You can now choose "Git: Add remote..." and then paste the repository's URL, instead of adding from Github.

Now committing and pushing should work as expected.

Comment: Excellent tip, but I've forgot to do the first commit and I was getting the error "failed to push some refs to [repository_url]" trying do push command, this was solved after making the first commit and than executing "git push -u [remote_name] master"

Answer (score 9):

I just wanted to add another workaround as I came across the same issue.

1. Publish as a private or public repository within your personal GitHub instance
2. Open the repository and go to "settings" (GitHub UI)
   [image]
3. Use the "transfer ownership" option to transfer the repository to your organization.
   [image]
4. Done. As from my experience tools like VS Code and VS 2022 will not loose the connection to the repository and you can still commit code without further changes (Assuming the correct permissions of the organization are provided to you).

Answer (score 2):

By default, GitHub allows you to publish to your own public or private repositories. To publish to an organization repository, follow the steps below -

1. Create an organization repository in GitHub, if not already created.
2. Press "Initialize Repository" in VS Code's "Source Control" and commit the code.
3. Open the Command Palette in VsCode by clicking **Ctrl+Shift+P**, select "**Git: Add Remote**", and paste your organization's repository URL. You can also open the "Source Control" tab, go to the **Remotes** section, click the plus sign, and paste the URL of your organization's repository.

This should add the repository as a remote. This enables you to push the code to your organization's repository.

**Handling Errors** - Sometimes we may get errors like "*failed to push some refs to...*". This occurs when your local repository hasn't been updated with the changes in the remote repository. To fix this error, open the terminal and execute the following commands -

- `git pull --rebase origin main`
- `git push -u origin main`

**NOTE-** The `origin` in the above command refers to the organization repository's URL.

If the first command is successful, you should get a response '*Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/main*'

Now whenever you push/pull any code, it will update seamlessly to/from the organization's repository.