# How to publish an organization repository in Github with VSCode

Tags: c#, git, github, visual-studio-code

I have a question with github. I created organisation repostory on Github with name TestOrganisation. However, VSCode sees the repositories in my personal account every time. How can I do the first publish to a repostory in an organization?

I am using microsoft github extension in vsCode. Can anyone help me please?

[image]

Comment: This is a question about *git*, not Github. All tools and editors see *the local* repositories. Git will pull or push to remote repositories but the editors always work on the local repositories. If you want to work on a remote repository you'll have to *pull* it locally and work on the files, then push any changes to the remote

Comment: VS Code can make this a bit easier, by signing in to Github and cloning an existing ithub repo. Check [Working with GitHub in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/github)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to publish an organization repository in Github using VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67508000/how-to-publish-an-organization-repository-in-github-using-vscode)